# KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener

Tags: android, keyboard-events

How can I disable swipeLeft()/swipeRight() methods, because it **intercepts onRelease() method** then I quickly moves the finger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution: I need invoke `onRelease()` in `swipeLeft()`.